Why should nozzles be perfectly expanded?
If I understand it correctly, the only problem with an overexpanded nozzle is (aside from technical difficulties) that the surrounding atmosphere puts pressure on the exhaust gases and reduces engine thrust and efficiency. So isn't it rather that the nozzle needs to be expanded enough to make the exhaust velocity as high as possible and still pay off due to the pressure? But this point of balance doesn't have to happen just when the pressures are equal, right?

Sure, that's why booster engines like the SSME are overexpanded for much of the ascent. The trick is to design the nozzle so that the flow doesn't separate.

An overexpanded nozzle may cause less thrust and increased dry mass, so less payload mass.

Rocket nozzles are ALWAYS overexpanded for sea level

Clarification request: By "point of balance", do you mean "point at which thrust is maximized" or "best practice when designing an engine"? I answered assuming the former, but the answer to the latter is quite different.

An engine's thrust is transmitted to the rocket via the pressure that the exhaust exerts on the interior surface of the nozzle. Note that this pressure is not uniform: it is very high where the nozzle is narrow, and lower on the wider parts of the nozzle. (IIUC, the interior pressure at a given "height" within the nozzle is inversely proportional to the cross-sectional area at that height.) If a nozzle is overexpanded, then on the lowest portion of the nozzle, the interior pressure is less than the ambient pressure of the atmosphere on the nozzle's exterior surface; so that portion of the nozzle is actually providing net negative thrust.
Note that flow separation actually alleviates this problem, but causes a bunch of other problems (like destroying the nozzle).
TL;DR Yes, the "point of balance" is necessarily exactly when the pressures are equal; this is the point where further expansion will actually reduce thrust (for the given ambient pressure).

I understand that any increase in nozzle expansion causes the resulting thrust to decrease due to pressure, but can't that still increase thrust as a result because the exhaust gases are accelerated more?

Note that the converging part of the nozzle also produces negative thrust. Also only the axial component of the pressure force matters for thrust, and this is quite small towards the nozzle exit.

@SaturnV Overexpanded exhaust compresses when it leaves the engine, slowing it down.

@SaturnV The acceleration of exhaust gas is not separate from the exertion of pressure. Just as the rocket is accelerated by the pressure of the gas on the nozzle, so the gas is accelerated by the equal and opposite pressure of the nozzle on the gas. Expressing everything in terms of pressure just makes some calculations easier (and others harder).

@SaturnV An extension of the nozzle does increase the velocity of the exhaust gases. But it also increases the amount of ambient air that the nozzle has to push out of the way. And for an overexpanded nozzle, the latter effect dominates.

@OrganicMarble As I understand it, the negative thrust of the converging part of the nozzle is more than balanced by the positive thrust on the "ceiling" (injection plate?) of the combustion chamber. My understanding is that the axial component of pressure is quite small toward the nozzle exit. In both cases, the apparent inefficiency is balanced by other considerations. (E.g., without the converging part, the exhaust velocity would be subsonic and the expanding part of the nozzle wouldn't work at all.)

Agree with all! I just don't think the negative thrust caused by the pressure force on the nozzle walls near the exit is very significant.

@OrganicMarble You'd think not, but the positive thrust that is captured by vacuum nozzle extensions is strictly less than the negative thrust contribution from sea-level ambient air. If the negative thrust contribution were actually insignificant, no one would bother with vacuum nozzle extensions. (Or overexpanded nozzles, by similar reasoning.) That having been said, I don't deny that in many actual use cases, the flow separation is much more significant than the negative thrust.

@JohnDoty While you are correct that overexpanded exhaust slows down after leaving the nozzle, IIUC the effects of that slowdown cannot propagate back up the exhaust stream to affect the thrust because the exhaust is supersonic.

@CharlesStaats That is correct, but the force on the outside of the nozzle balances the force downstream even though they are not connected through the exhaust stream.
